# Python Split String With Multiple Separators

Tags: python

I am trying to parse Python sentences with multiple delimiters. Here is what I did.

```
delimiters = " \t,;.?!-:@[](){}_*/"
def get_words(sentence):
    parsed_sentence = sentence
    delimiter = []
    for i in range(len(delimiters)):
        delimiter.append(delimiters[i])
    new_sentence = ""
    for i in range(len(parsed_sentence)):
        if(parsed_sentence[i] not in delimiter):
            new_sentence = new_sentence + parsed_sentence[i]
        else:
            new_sentence = new_sentence + " "
           
    new_list = new_sentence.split(" ")
    ret = []
    for element in new_list:
        if(element.lower() not in stopWordsList and element != ''):
            ret.append(element.lower())
    return ret
```

I was wondering if there is a much shorter way of doing this. Also, I would need to eliminate trailing whitespaces too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use re, either with specific or special characters. E.g.

```py
import re

delimiters = r"[ \t\n\,\;\.\?\!\-\:\@\[\]\(\)\{\}\_\*\/\]]"
list(filter(lambda x: x != '', re.split(delimiters, lorem)))
```

In case you need the words, you can use the pattern `r"[^\w]"`.

```py
import re

delimiters = r"[^\w]"
list(filter(lambda x: x != '', re.split(delimiters, lorem)))
```

Comment: There's no need to escape `,`, `;`, etc. in the regexp.